# Point a new domain at existing files but keep new domain url

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, .htaccess

I have a directory: `http://mysite.com/somedir/`

I have a new domain: `http://myothersite.com`

I want my new domain to point to the files in `http://mysite.com/somedir/` but retain it's own url. So that a visit to:

`http://myothersite.com/` will load the files at `http://mysite.com/somedir/`

or a visit to:

`http://myothersite.com/stories/` will load the files at `http://mysite.com/somedir/stories/`

but the url doesn't change (i.e. I don't want to redirect).

My question...
**Is there a way to do this without physically duplicating and moving the files so they exist in two locations?**

Comment: You should read the apache documentation on name based virtual hosting.

Comment: I recognise sarcasm when I see it but it really is good advice. Reading documentation is a great learning experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be best handled by using virtual hosts.

On Ubuntu, it can be done as follows:

First, copy the existing site configuration file for your original domain. If you haven't toyed with much, it will be located at /etc/apache2/sites-available/default . I recommend naming the copy whatever the name of your new domain is, but you can use whatever you want.

e.g.

```
sudo cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/default /etc/apache2/sites-available/myothersite.com
```

Open the original file with your favorite text editor, e.g.

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
```

and insert the following line after the `ServerAdmin` line:

```
ServerName mysite.com
```

Afterwards, open the copy you made, e.g.,

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/myothersite.com
```

Insert a line under the `ServerAdmin` line:

```
ServerName mynewsite.com
```

Underneath this, you will see the `DocumentRoot` directive, followed by a directory, usually `/var/www`. Add the directory your files are in to the end of this, i.e. `/var/www/somedir`.

After doing this, activate the new virtual host with the command

```
sudo a2ensite myothersite.com
```

To make the changes active, restart Apache with

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

and you're all done.